# Npm module "grunt-contrib-imagemin" not found, Is it installed?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I run into this error, when I try to do build a project with "grunt build".

[image: Screenshot]

There seems to be no problem when I test the project by doing "grunt server".

The project has been scaffolded and managed with: yeoman/grunt/bower. In Windows.

Everything went well and then a week ago or so it started doing this. I can't build projects no more.

When I try to install the module doing:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin
```

It can never install it, get the following "weird" error.

[image]

Any hints please?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok I found a way to solve this:

- In your package.json, add "jpegtran-bin": "0.2.0" before the reference to imagemin
- Delete the node_modules folder in your project, and run "npm install" and "bower install" again

There seem to be an issue with the jpegtran's latest version.

!! - Please note this is just a workarround waiting for the bugfix.

Comment: It works for me too. Please note it's just a workaround waiting a bugfix. :)

Answer (score 6):

Like the program suggests, you need to install the `npm` module.

```
npm i --save-dev grunt-contrib-imagemin
```

Considering you're on Windows you might want to take a look [at the project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) for additional installation instructions.

Answer (score 3):

There's an issue with a package contrib-imagemin references that prevents it from properly installing on Windows.

GitHub issue on grunt-contrib-imagemin: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/109

GitHub pull request on the offending library: https://github.com/yeoman/node-jpegtran-bin/pull/38

For now, you can manually specify "jpegtran-bin": "0.2.0" in your package.json and it should function as a workaround. If it's a pain point for you, go comment on that pull request and perhaps it'll convince the project maintainer to actually take a look and comment as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with 0.3.0 version, but once I updated to 0.4.0 the problem was solved. Check your package.json. Hope that helps!

```
"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.4.0",
```

Comment: I am using version 0.7.1 and still get it

Comment: I had the problem when I already had 0.4.0, so I'm not sure it's that…

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2015 I solved this by deleting node_modules and running npm install.

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows, I was getting same error. 
So I edited the `Environmental Variables`.

Just add: `C:\Ruby200-x64\bin` to your `PATH` variable and restart node prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The `imagemin` install seems to not run correctly when called by `grunt-contrib-imagemin`.  I just do

```
cd ./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin
npm install
```

And then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, package.json containing:

```
 "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.4.0",
```

I had to reinstall Grunt (but the `jpegtran-bin` workaround, or just removing node_modules and running `npm install` wasn't enough, I needed the following (with sudo):

```
rm -rf node_modules/
sudo npm update -g npm
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```